# What is the purpose of Facebook "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

What is the purpose of Facebook "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" and how to use it?

What I should have on this URL?

Does Facebook send any data to the URL when a user is logged in using the Facebook Login on my site?

Here is a question about some redirecting but I think it is not OAuth Redirect: [purpose of redirect URI in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427461/purpose-of-redirect-uri-in-facebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" can be configured in My Apps > {your app} > Facebook Login > Settings.

"**Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**", which I'll call only `redirect_uri`, is used when you **[Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)**.

In this case `redirect_uri` is a URL to which your web user is redirected after login.

Facebook sends `code` and `state` as URL parameters when redirect to `redirect_uri`.

On the `redirect_uri` on your http server you should have a programming code which verify the `state` and use the `code` to get an `access_token`.

### Example how to make server side API calls:

#### 1. Your login page

On your web page (e.g. `https://yourdomain.com/fb-login.html`) you have the following Login link:

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/v9.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=111&redirect_uri=https%3A//yourdomain.com/fb-auth.html&state=mystate123">Login</a>
```

`111` is you Facebook App ID.

`https%3A//yourdomain.com/fb-auth.html` is your `redirect_uri` and has to match what you configured in "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs".

`mystate123` is your custom state or kind of session ID which you can use to verify that the callback is initiated from your login page. Facebook: "A string value created by your app to maintain state between the request and callback.".

#### 2. Facebook Login window

When the user click "Login" the Facebook Login window appears and she/he enters her/his username and password. After that, on successful login, the user is redirected to
`https://yourdomain.com/fb-auth.html?code=JQJc5CF&state=mystate123`

#### 3. Extract parameters from the callback

When the GET request of the above URL hits your http server you have to extract the `code` and should extract the `state` from the URL.

#### 4. Verify the state (optional)

You can verify that the `state` is matching the `state` you provided on your Login button at fb-login.html

#### 5. Get access_token

On your **server** you have to make another GET request to get an access_token. This is **server to server** call, thus you can include your `client_secret`. **WARNING**: Never include your `client_secret` in client-side code!

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=111&redirect_uri=https%3A//yourdomain.com/fb-auth.html&client_secret=222&code=JQJc5CF
```

The response is:

```
{
  "access_token": "IEESb4Z",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

#### 6. Make API calls

Now you can use the access token to make API calls:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=IEESb4Z
```