# Having trouble with the authentication process of logging in Facebook from my Django project

Tags: django, facebook, social-authentication

I am new to Django and I wanted to build a Django application that could allow users to log in using Facebook, so I have followed every step listed in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/django-authentication-with-facebook-instagram-and-linkedin). Despite following the same step, I still getting errors after providing my password and click on the continue button. Here are two errors that I've encountered:

> URL blocked
>
> This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

> The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

My configuration for the app in Facebook developers

```
valid OAuth Redirect URIs: https://127.0.0.1:8000/
app domains: localhost
site url: https://localhost:8000/
```

I tried to search for clues everywhere but found nothing in the end. How can I make it work?

Comment: hey, you are missing information. like details of your virtual environment and packages used. but leave out info such as your secret key.

Comment: Hi, I am using a virtual environment to run this project. I used this command line to create the venv: "conda create --name myDjango python=3.10.6". While for the package, I am using social-auth-app-django.

Comment: Why would you use a host name for some, and then an IP address for another of those URLs? AFAIK, this doesn't work with IP addresses at all, you _must_ use URLs with a host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda understand what is wrong now. I have a button in my web app for social authentication for facebook `<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with Facebook</a>`. Once I've changed the link of this button to `https://www.facebook.com/v9.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=your_app_id&redirect_uri=your_oauth_redirect_uri&state=yourstate_1234` (the redirect_uri in the URL should match exactly the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in facebook app) and it worked! Here is a more [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177548/what-is-the-purpose-of-facebook-valid-oauth-redirect-uris) that helped me. Btw, thanks to those who replied :)